# Who is second from the left in the photo of the Salonika Trial Indictees (1917)?

Tags: world-war-one, identification

In the wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Archduke_Franz_Ferdinand#Salonika_trial_(spring_1917)) for the Salonika Trial, which proceeded from the assassination of Archduke Franz Ferdinand, there's this photo:

[image: Indictees at the Salonika trial, after the verdict.]

> *Indictees at the Salonika trial, after the verdict.*

Does anyone know the name of the person who is second from the left?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome on History.SE ! Have you already identified the other characters ?

Comment: The person on the far left is [Dragutin Dimitrijević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragutin_Dimitrijevi%C4%87_Apis), and the far right is [Ljubomir Vulović](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ljubomir_Vulovi%C4%87). I couldn't find any information on the others.

Comment: Thank you @jeff-lambert and @evargalo! That'll be useful in helping to narrow it down. I was able to locate a book at my library that might offer some more information, but as of right now I've been unable to identify any of the other people in the photo.

Comment: In addition to Dragutin Dimitrijević and Ljubomir Vulović, other people present in this photo are [Muhamed Mehmedbašić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhamed_Mehmedba%C5%A1i%C4%87), Rade Malobabić, Damjan Popović and Bogdan Radenković. But I don't know which is which.

Based on another picture of Muhamed from 1917, I believe he's second from the right.

Comment: Note, I'm not 100% certain that Damjan Popović and Bogdan Radenković are in this photo, but I have seen their names on a list of the indicted at this trial.

Comment: Wikipedia says that man in the middle in front row is Rade Malobabić . There are no other photos of him on net, at least I could not find any, so it is impossible to confirm .

Comment: But to add, authenticity of the photo is unconfirmed, it was uploaded on Wikipedia without credible source , and whole scene is surreal with man condemned to death posing casually with unknown girl .

Comment: That's a very good point, @rs.29, about authenticity. The surrealness of the photo was part of what prompted my query, in addition to my general curiosity as to who the woman was. Either way, it's definitely Dragutin Dimitrijević and Ljubomir Vulović in the photo, and possibly Muhamed Mehmedbašić as well, so it seems quite possible this is a a picture of the Black Hand. If that at least is true, does anyone know of any female members of the Black Hand?

Comment: @Lukas Highly unlikely, but there were female sympathizers of societies like "Narodna Odbrana" which were somewhat connected with Black Hand. But very few Serbian women actually crossed Albania with Serbian army in winter of 1915/16, so identity of the girl in the picture is very intriguing.